# How to setup distributed orientDB (Enterprise edition 2.2.9) in Sharding mode

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

I am using Oriednt DB enterprose 2.2.9 edition for my project. I have set the 2 server cluster for now and implemented the sharding in distributed environment. But when i am pulling data from RDBMS using teleporter, data is not distributing. Its simply replicating the data in two servers. So can you please help me in setup a distributed environment

My Config files are as follows:-

**default-distributed-db-config.json:-**
{
    "replication": true,
    "clusters": {
        "internal": {
            "replication": false
        },
        "index": {
            "replication": false
        },
        "ODistributedConflict": {
            "replication": false
        },
        "*": {
            "replication": true,
            "writeQuorum": 2,
            "partitioning": {
                "strategy": "round-robin",
                "default": 0,
                "partitions": [
                        [ "manoj" ],
            [ "vishnu" ]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

**hazelcast.xml**

    
        orientdb
        orientdb
    
    
        false
        false
        false
        5
        1
        1
        1
        1

```
</properties>
<network>
    <port auto-increment="true">2434</port>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false">
            <multicast-group>235.1.1.1</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>2434</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                            <member>10.22.20.101:2434</member>
                            <member>10.22.20.122:2434</member>
                    </tcp-ip>

    </join>
</network>
<executor-service>
    <pool-size>16</pool-size>
</executor-service>
```

Comment: Have you seen official documentation? http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Sharding.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you try delete `distributed-config.json` so OrientDB will read from `default-distributed-db-config.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is invalid (that's an old, outdated version).  Some of the 2.2 docs still reflected it, and I removed the references.

Better information is here and what Oleksandr sent you:
http://orientdb.com/docs/master/Distributed-Configuration-Tuning.html

-Colin